Where should a bromine attack after HBr addition on given alkene?

What should be the major product of following reaction?


My teacher said the latter one with $\ce{Br}$ on para-position (to oxygen on the ring) will be major but shouldn't the first product be major because of back bonding?

Under KCP conditions the 3 degree pi bond would form the carbocation on the 3 degree carbon and that is where Bromine would attack.
Under TCP conditions (considered usually above room temperature i.e. 298 K) the same pi bond would break but now the other pi bond would resonate with the carbocation as this would give the pi bond more Hyperconjugation structures and then Bromine would attack at meta position wrt Methyl group.
KCP - Kinetically controlled Product.
TCP - Thermodynamically controlled Product.
wrt - with respect to.

What's s 3 degree pi bond or a 3 degree carbon?

a 3 degree carbon is a carbon attached to 3 more carbons and by the 3 degree pi bond I meant to refer the exocyclic pi bond on the 3 degree carbon

That certainly is not standard nomenclature.
